# Linear dependency of vectors of functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra, symbolic

I would like to find a symbolic way to obtain a Q-function (Boolean output) for the following problem.
I have the following inputs:

```
v1={F11[t],F12[t],F13[t],...}
v2={F21[t],F22[t],F23[t],...}
...

vn={Fn1[t],Fn2[t],Fn3[t],...}
```

That is lists of functions, properly defined beforehand.
I would like to know the rank, that is the max number of linear independent vectors of functions in the matrix:

```
V={v1,v2,...,vn};
```

I would actually want mathematica to even generate more solutions, according to possible parametric assumptions on such functions.
Say `F1=a Sin[t]`, if necessary I would like to know for which values of a the rank would be n, n-1, ... 0.
I tried MatrixRank, but I believe this only works with numerical lists.
Is there a more correct way to do this?

Comment: Try MatrixRank as a function of $t$.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I recon MatrixRank is based on Gaussian elimination

Comment: Play with Function[t, MatrixRank[V]][x] (in your notations) for various values of x.

Comment: Have you seen `Wronskian[]` and `Casoratian[]` already?

Comment: Yes but wronskian tells me about linear dependency of single couples of functions. As far as I know it does not handle vectors of functions